# Visual Studio Setup --> Change the Installation Directory with informations from registry

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation, setup-project

I want to change the installdir via a custom action (beforeInstall) or so. How can I do this?
I found only tips to change the directory to a specialfolder like appdata or so.

the best would be if I change the directory before the directory is shown to the user. is there a way?

my planned steps:

1. start setup
2. determine a registry entry
3. change the INSTALLDIR
4. show the user this directory
5. continue with normal procedure of the setup

if using something like

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class MyInstallerHelper : Installer
{
    protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        // 1. I don't know how to change the installdir
        // 2. the installation is started already
    }
}
```

p. s.
I found something like that, but it is not exactly what i want because the installdir is only written in a file and not changed
http://vbcity.com/forums/p/145818/624707.aspx

Comment: I'd recommend ditching the setup project and using a decent installation authoring package (e.g. Wix). Doing registry searches at appropriate times, and using those to set properties are facilities built into such systems. VS setup projects have *lots* of limitations.